# Values are not passing

Tags: python, list, class, methods

For my following class function

```
    def add_vertex(self,vertex):   
        for i in range(self.num_vertices):
            if self.vertices[i] == vertex:
                return

        self.vertices[self.num_vertices]=vertex
        for i in range(self.num_vertices):
            self.edges[self.num_vertices][i]=0
            self.edges[i][self.num_vertices]=0
        self.num_vertices +=1


    def add_edges(self,from_vertex,to_vertex,weight):
        row=self.index_is(from_vertex)
        col=self.index_is(to_vertex)
        self.edges[row][col]=weight
```

When I put these values

```
i=0
while i<len(to):
    my_graph.add_vertex(from_[i])
    my_graph.add_edges(from_[i],to[i],distance[i])
    i=i+1
```

But the value aren't passing
values for from_[],to[] and distance[]

```
['Luebeck', 'Hamburg', 'Hamburg', 'Hamburg', 'Bremen', 'Bremen', 'Hannover', 'Hannover', 'Magdeburg', 'Berlin', 'Dresden', 'Leipzig', 'Dortmund', 'Kassel', 'Frankfurt', 'Frankfurt', 'Leipzig', 'Dortmund', 'Saarbruecken', 'Saarbruecken', 'Karlsruhe', 'Stuttgart', 'Stuttgart', 'Stuttgart', 'Nuremberg', 'Manchester', 'Birmingham', 'Birmingham']

['Hamburg', 'Bremen', 'Hannover', 'Berlin', 'Hannover', 'Dortmund', 'Magdeburg', 'Kassel', 'Berlin', 'Dresden', 'Leipzig', 'Magdeburg', 'Duesseldorf', 'Frankfurt', 'Dortmund', 'Nuremberg', 'Nuremberg', 'Saarbruecken', 'Frankfurt', 'Karlsruhe', 'Stuttgart', 'Frankfurt', 'Munich', 'Nuremberg', 'Munich', 'Birmingham', 'Bristol', 'London']

['63', '116', '153', '291', '132', '234', '148', '165', '166', '204', '119', '125', '69', '185', '221', '222', '263', '350', '177', '143', '71', '200', '215', '207', '171', '84', '85', '117']
```

Comment: "the value aren't passing values for from_[],to[] and distance[]" - We prefer to have proper descriptions,  not riddles.

Comment: When you say, "they aren't passing", what exactly is happening? What do you see, and what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to implement a **Graph** using list the values aren't passing but if i pass values one by one then it worked

Answer (score 0):

Among other issues (hint: look up how enumerate works), 
  Your code won't work as written because you only add the from vertices and so when it comes time to look up the stuff in to, you're get an error (in addition, even if something that is in to is also in from, you're going to hit an issue where you are trying to add the edge before you add the vertex.  The best way to keep most of your code is to change your feeding of data to instead be something like:

```
for i in xrange(len(from_):
    g.add_vertex(from_[i])
for i in xrange(len(to):
    g.add_vertex(to[i])

for i in xrange(min(len(_from),len(to),len(weight)))
    g.add_edges(_from[i],to[i],weight[i])
```

(where the min is just to make sure your 3 lists are the same length)